# Passing a parameter value to a simple function in R

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and am struggling to understand why my code below does not work.

I am using the flights dataset in the nycflights13 library. I want to be able to write a function that calculates the mean of a variable which I specify in the function parameter. For example, the code below works fine:

```
summarise(group_by(flights, year, month), 
          avg = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However, when I try to put this inside a function and calculate the average of arr_delay, I get an error:

```
summarise_func <- function(var = dep_delay) {
  summarise(group_by(flights, year, month), 
            avg = mean(var, na.rm = TRUE))
}
summarise_func(var = arr_delay)
```

> *Error in mean(var, na.rm = TRUE) : object 'arr_delay' not found*

Can someone please explain to me why the value of the var parameter (arr_delay) is not passed to the function and how to get around this?

I am fully aware I can just write another piece of code to calculate the average arr_delay but I am trying to figure out how R works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put things into functions it starts to become a bit complicated. Read about non-standard evaluation (NSE).

For now, you can use curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator to pass unquoted column names in the function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(nycflights13)

summarise_func <- function(flights, var = dep_delay) {
    flights %>%
      group_by(year, month) %>%
      summarise(avg = mean({{var}}, na.rm = TRUE))
}

summarise_func(flights, arr_delay)

#    year month    avg
#   <int> <int>  <dbl>
# 1  2013     1  6.13 
# 2  2013     2  5.61 
# 3  2013     3  5.81 
# 4  2013     4 11.2  
# 5  2013     5  3.52 
# 6  2013     6 16.5  
# 7  2013     7 16.7  
# 8  2013     8  6.04 
# 9  2013     9 -4.02 
#10  2013    10 -0.167
#11  2013    11  0.461
#12  2013    12 14.9
```

Trying the default option

```
summarise_func(flights)

#    year month   avg
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1  2013     1 10.0 
# 2  2013     2 10.8 
# 3  2013     3 13.2 
# 4  2013     4 13.9 
# 5  2013     5 13.0 
# 6  2013     6 20.8 
# 7  2013     7 21.7 
# 8  2013     8 12.6 
# 9  2013     9  6.72
#10  2013    10  6.24
#11  2013    11  5.44
#12  2013    12 16.6
```